# Cannot Mock an Injected Dependency in Controller Constructor

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am having a problem with mocking an object being injected in to a controller.

I am running an integration test.  In my test I have the following setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthenticationTests {

@TestConfiguration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AbstractClient client() {
        return new AbstractClient() {

            @Override
            public ManagedChannel getChannel() {
                return new ManagedChannel();
            }
        };
    }
    }
}
```

In the controller being tested, `AbstractClient` is dependency injected like so:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    private ManagedChannel managedChannel;
    public MyController(AbstractClient client) {
      managedChannel = client.getChannel();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the test, AbstractClient defined in the @TestConfiguration class is never injected - instead the default one is (which is annotated as @Service).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your  configuration needs to be  a `public static` class.

Comment: Changing to public static doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: How is the `MyController` bean instantiated in your test ? Where is your test code ?

Comment: My understanding is that by annotating @SpringBootTest, the entire spring boot application was instantiated - which would also instantiate MyController (and its associated routes)?

Comment: Also - the reason why I am using @SpringBootTest is to actually test some authentication code that is inside a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - this seemed to be the only way to do it. Other tests are plain unit tests of the controllers.

Comment: Just use `@MockBean` to inject your channel (or your full client).